# How to you say "is differentiated from" or "differentiates to" in one equation?

Tags: calculus

How do you say "is differentiated from" or "differentiates to" in a single equation?

At the moment I am doing $f(x)=x^2,\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$

I want something along the lines of $\text{____}x^2\text{____}=2x$ I am looking for the thing that goes through the gap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the conventional variants:
$$
(x^2)'=2x, \qquad {d\over dx}x^2 = 2x.
$$

This can be read as:

$ \quad \quad $ *The derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$.*

$ \quad \quad $ *The first derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$.*

**Note:** I have never seen anyone say "is differentiated from" before (when speaking about derivatives). Instead, it is better to say something like

$ \quad \quad $ *We differentiate $x^2$ and get $2x$.*

$ \quad \quad $ *Differentiating $x^2$ we get $2x$.*

Answer (score 0):

You could try:$$\frac{d}{dx}x^2=2x$$

Comment: The $y$ shouldn't be there.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.